# Read values from a Dynamic Object C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, dynamicobject

I'm trying to read values from System.Web.Helpers.DynamicJsonObject. I can see the values in the debugger but I can't figure out how to access them. I have tried this

`item.GetType().GetProperty("batch_id").GetValue(item, null);`

but when I try that I get this response in the debugger "item.GetType().GetProperty("batch_id")' is null"

I have attached a picture from my solution
[image]

Thank you,
-Tesh

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is dynamic so you can just do:

```
string batchId = item.batch_id;
```

If for some reason you have the property name in a `string`, and don't know it at compile time, the indexing operator will work:

```
string value = item["batch_id"];
```

Comment: Thanks driss, that worked perfectly. I'm glad you mentioned the item["batch_id"], because that was my next question :).

Comment: Please can you explain in which case property names would be in "string" and in which case as normal properties ?

Answer (score 4):

Try enumerating the values [DynamicJsonObject.GetDynamicMemberNames Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.dynamicjsonobject.getdynamicmembernames%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). It returns an *IEnumerable* of *string*.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because they are fields, not properties. And, yeah, it is dynamic, so you can use just `item.batch_id`.